# Copying non-spatial data from Oracle database to file geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I have a model (shown below) that runs fine minus one small portion (outlined in red). I have tried various ways to remedy this but to no avail. The issue I'm having is this: The top portion of the model runs smoothly, as it is pulling data from an Oracle dB that has geometry (via the 'Make Query Layer' tool), and therefore I'm able to use the 'Copy Features' tool in order to store it in a File Geodatabase. This, as you may know, is because the 'Copy Features' tool only accepts a Feature Class or a Layer that has spatial attributes as input. Ergo, when it comes time to run the portion below it, I cannot use 'Copy Features', as it will not accept the 'Make Query Layer' of something from oracle that is not spatial, due to it simply being a table. So in its place, I am using 'Make Table View', which successfully accepts my 'Make Query Layer' as input. However, the error message seen below appears when it comes time to run itself. The rest of the model then takes the result of the 'Make Table View', and runs 'Make XY Event Layer' (as the table being pulled has an X/Y column for coordinates). From there, I then run the 'Copy Features' tool to import it into a File Geodatabase. Oddly enough, I also receive an error (listed below) if I try to simply go straight from the 'Make Query Layer' output and use it as the input for the 'Make XY Event Layer'. Trying the tool 'Copy Rows', also receives an error.

Is anyone aware of any other way in which you can pull non-spatial data (e.g. a table) and then somehow transfer it to a File Geodatabase Table?

I've searched through the other tools that seemed intuitive enough to look for, but had no such luck.

[image: Model Builder]

[image: Error Message]

[image: Make Table View]

[image: Error #2]

[image: Copy Rows]

Comment: Can't quite read your model in the picture above but  - Why can't you use the **Table to Table** Tool in your model?

Comment: @ User23715 - You are exactly right. I knew there was a simple way/fix for this but for whatever reason couldn't remember the name of the tool. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Table to Table' tool will accomplish the task, as it 'Converts an input table to a dBASE or geodatabase table'.